# Allow scrolling listview after setSelection

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview which I am forcefully scrolling to the bottom of the list, whenever the list is updated. However, after scrolling to the bottom of the list, for some reason, the listview becomes fixated at that point and the user cannot scroll back and forth on the list to see the other data.

Question: After `setSelection(list.getBottom())`, what should I have in order to allow scrolling through the entire list once again?

```
    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        /* the list is being populated here - the code has been omitted */          

            list.populateFrom(date, name, class);
            list.clearFocus();
            list.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    list.setSelection(list.getBottom());
                }
            });


        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with the fact that you are calling

```
 list.setSelection(list.getBottom());
```

in `getView()`, which is called **every single time** the ListView needs more Views drawn. This means you constantly scroll down.

Instead, update the data set you have from *outside* the `Adapter` class (such as from an `Activity/Fragment`), then either reset the `ListView`'s adapter or clear the adapter and readd the items, then call `setSelection()`.

One way to do this:

- `Activity` starts an `AsyncTask`
- `AsyncTask` updates a `List` of data via `doInBackground()`.
- In `onPostExecute()`, instantiate the `Adapter` with the `List` passed from `doInBackground()`. Or clear the data set of the `Adapter` you currently have, then loop through the List and re-add the items to the `Adapter`.
- If reinstantiating the `Adapter`, set the `ListView`'s `Adapter` to what you have created.
- call `ListView#setSelection()`

Comment: thanks for the awesome explanation! I moved my setSelction somewhere else and now it works perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   cus= new Customlistadapter(paramets for customer adapter));//Custom list adapter
   lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
   lv1.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
   lv1.setStackFromBottom(true);
   cus.notifyDataSetChanged();// for refreshing listview with updates
   lv1.setAdapter(cus);
   cus.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
   @Override
   public void onChanged() {
    super.onChanged();
    lv1.setSelection(cus.getCount() - 1);    
   }
 });
```

Use the above in your activity class. A--C has pointed to the problem.

If you are using AysncTask in your activity class try the below code.

```
  private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, VOid> {
 protected void onPreExecute()
 {
     //display progress dialog
 }
 protected Long doInBackground(Void... params) {
   // get data from server
     return null;
 }


 protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {
  // dismiss dialog
  //set  data
  // paste the above listview code here. 
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by A--C, it is problem with the

> list.setSelection(list.getBottom());

Every time your getView() is called you are moving/scrolling the view to the bottom, there fore when you are trying to scroll the view again then your getView() is called and again you again move to bottom.
So instead of setting the selection in the listview to the bottom in the getView() you should do it in your activity/fragment.
In activity you observe the change and set selection to the bottom.

*If this was helpful explanation for your problem, do upvote*